# Still cannot choose "Virtual Machines" as a resource when adding an environment, while it should be available according to sprint 162 release notes

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

According to the [release notes of sprint 162](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-162-update#vm-deployments-with-environments), we can now use `Virtual machines` as a resources for deployments.

However, when adding an environment I can still only choose `Kubernetes`. All other changes mentioned in the release notes do seem to be available. Is there anything I need to enable or set-up to be able to use this feature?

The `new enviroment` dialog still looks like this:

[image: Our "new environment" dialog]

While according to the release notes, it should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New features are rolled out gradually, see the "Next steps section" from the end of the release notes.

> These features will roll out over the next two to three weeks -
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-162-update#next-steps

EDIT: The organisation I work for has several Azure DevOps Organisations, one has access to the `Virtual Machines`resource (location == UK south), the others do not(location == West Europe). We did not have to do anything for the `Virtual Machines` resource to become available to us in our UK South organisation.